# How to access a file outside from a docker container?

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, file-not-found

I am using django as my framework.
To manage the server we are using docker.

When I try to run:

```
docker-compose exec -T  web python3 manage.py shell < /data01/ipse/litework/second_level_controller/load.py
```

to load some data I get the following Error:

> File "/code/second_level_controller/DataBaseLoader.py", line 53, in load_filenames
> with open(os.path.join(self.data_directory, 'manifest.txt')) as f:
>
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> '/data01/ipse/rawdata/manifest.txt'

But the file /data01/ipse/rawdata/manifest.text exists and I can acces the file normally with:

```
nano /data01/ipse/rawdata/manifest.txt
```

How can I access the file correctly?

Comment: It looks like that file is a sort of script to the Django management app; does it reference other files inside the script with absolute paths?  How did you originally start the container?

Answer (score 2):

Trying adding a volume mount for /data01 so that those files are in the same location inside your docker image.

https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volume-configuration-reference

This would look something like:

```
services:
  webserver:
    image: python
    volumes:
       - /data01:/data01
```

Comment: Not exactly my answer but it led me in the right direction. Thanks!